# Inability to create my UIImageView classes from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, cocoa-touch

I am creating subclasses of `UIImageView` class, something like `LittleImageView`, `RedImageView`, etc.

These subclasses have this convenience method for the creation of specific images:

```
+ (UIImageView *)novo {
   UIImageView *newImage = [[super alloc] initWithImage:...
   // do stuff
   return newImage;
 }
```

When I try to create such classes using this new command by string

```
id newObject = [NSClassFromString(nameOfClass) novo];
```

I get a crash with "unrecognized selector sent to class". Apparently objective-c is trying to do a `[UIImageView novo]` instead of doing a `[RedImageView novo]`, for instance.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your experience exactly, but there are a few changes you should consider:  (1) declare the constructor as returning the derived type, (2) declare the local variable as the derived type, (3) used the derived class to alloc (self, not super)...

```
// in MyImageView.h
+ (instancetype)myImageView:(UIImage *)image;

// in MyImageView.m
+ (instancetype)myImageView:(UIImage *)image {
    MyImageView *miv = [[self alloc] initWithImage:image];
    // ...
    return miv;
}
```

Now you can use elsewhere without the sketchy use of `id` in your local variable declaration.  It looks like this, and in my test, generates instances of the correct type...

```
MyImageView *firstTry = [MyImageView myImageView:nil];
MyImageView *secondTry = [NSClassFromString(@"MyImageView") myImageView:nil];

NSLog(@"%@, %@", firstTry, secondTry);
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right about the `instancetype` and the `self` instead of `super`... those make everything more correct. I have changed everything as you say but when I create the objects and then check their classes they are all still `UIImageViews`!

Comment: So, no more crash, but logging something like [firstTry class] you get an image view?  It works correctly when I run the code in this answer.

Comment: That is very strange. I remember using this in the past and I don't remember seeing this kind of behavior.

Comment: It's very important to alloc self in the derived class, not super.

Comment: and when the class does not have init, like `CIFilter` that is initialized as `[CIFilter filterWithName...` ? (note: I am also using the same approach to create `CIFilter` based classes and I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: Remember, we're talking about the alloc, but when init is not implemented in the derived class, the inherited init will be invoked.

Comment: No, I am talking when init is not implemented on the super class.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  A simple init is inherited by every subclass of NSObject, and in the case we're discussing, initWithImage is inherited too.  When you alloc `super`, you are allocating the superclass, creating an instance of the superclass.  All the other declaration doesn't matter, including the type of variable you assign it too.  Those are just casts, compile time descriptions of what you expect, not what actually happens

Comment: After reviewing all the code I have my `UIImageView` subclasses working now but not the `CIFilter` ones. What I mean is, read my question again for `CIFilter` based objects not `UIImageView` and your solution will not work. I cannot create a `CIFilter` object by doing `[[CIFilter alloc] init]`, isn't it? Probably some limitation of the `CIFilter` class, or whatever. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Happy to review the CIFilter code.  Do you want to create a new question about that specifically, posting the link here?

Comment: thanks. here we go... [this is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821358/inability-to-create-my-cifilter-classes-from-string) of the `CIFilter` problem.